# Internet inside VE with fedora 14 and openvz rhel6 repo

Tags: openvz

Ok, so here is the set up:

I've got fedora 14 running inside latest virtualbox with nat and networking is working. Inside this fedora I have installed openvz from the rhel6 repository and have setup a Suse 11.1 x86 VE. I'm using venet device and have also set up the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

From the VE I can ping the hardware node, but  I can't get past the hw node. Ping from VE return "icmp host unreachable" and by sniffing venet0:0 with tcpdump I can see traffic coming from the VE.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure it's eth0?

Comment: Fixed it, turned out that fedora had some default rule which was dropping everything in the FORWARD chain.